# Email One Click Buy

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, transaction

Does anyone have a suggestion how to implement a one-click purchase mechanism via SFMC email?

Intending for a customer to receive an email, when they click the CTA button, it automatically purchases the described product, directs the subscriber to a transaction confirmation page, then automatically triggers a receipt email.

Do you have any examples or case studies?

Cheers,
-Mike

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a specific example of this scenario, but it should be achievable, depending on what API methods are available from your ecommerce platform.

I'd look at achieving this by building a landing page in a microsite or CloudPage, passing any required order and customer details as URL parameters to the page and:

1. Use [SSJS](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/server_side_javascript/server_side_javascript_syntax_guide/) to make an `HTTP.Post()` request to the OAuth endpoint of your ecommerce platform (assuming it uses one).
2. Use the access token retrieved from step 1 to make another `HTTP.Post()` request to the API method of your ecommerce platform used to create an order, setting the access token retrieved from step 1 as a variable, for example: `var access_token = 'Bearer ' + obj[0].access_token` and retrieving URL parameters required for the order using `Request.GetQueryStringParameter()` SSJS function.
3. [Send a Triggered Email using AMPscript](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/using_ampscript_with_the_web_service_api/create_a_triggered_send_using_ampscript_and_the_soap_web_service_api/).
4. Display a confirmation message on the page.